# How do I append these two XMLs together?

Tags: javascript, xml

I'm trying to append xmlTwo inside the xmlOne yellow node, but I'm getting an error. What am I doing wrong?

```js
var xmlOne = 
    $.parseXML(
      "<xml xmlns=\"mynamespace\">\
        <red>\
          <orange>\
            <yellow>\
            </yellow>\
          </orange>\
        </red>\
      </xml>"
    );

var xmlTwo =
    $.parseXML(
      "<green>\
        <blue>I'm in blue!</blue>\
      </green>"
    );

var xmlThree = xmlOne.getElementsByTagName("yellow")[0].appendChild(xmlTwo);

console.log(xmlThree);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse the first element, the root one. 
Keep the second XML element as string.
Find the node in the first element where you want to append the other XML.
Append the XML into the node.

```
var xmlOne = 
    $.parseXML(
      "<xml xmlns=\"mynamespace\">\
        <red>\
          <orange>\
            <yellow>\
            </yellow>\
          </orange>\
        </red>\
      </xml>"
    );

var xmlTwoNotParsed =
      "<green>\
        <blue>I'm in blue!</blue>\
      </green>";

var yellowNode = $(xmlOne).find("yellow");
yellowNode.append(xmlTwoNotParsed);

console.log(xmlOne);
```